# carousel indicators bootstrap 4 not taking the css style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to style the bootstrap 4 carousel indicators like in the picture below, but I'm unable to do so.

[image]

```css
.carousel-indicators {
    width: auto;
    padding: 8px 18px;
    background-color: rgba(96,107,114,.8);
    border-radius: 18px;
    line-height: 0;
   
}


.carousel-indicators li {
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<ul class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The width of the background is more in my case. I have tried with positioning and translate but unable to do so. I'm unable to achieve like the picture above.
Can someone help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it work by using `!important`. This is required as it needs to overwrite bootstrap's styles.

It is highly discouraged to use this method. I would suggest you to use Bootstrap Sass to generate the css required for your need. You have variables to define the style in _variables file.

---

Ok, I didn't read the full question before answering. There are some default bootstrap classes which you need to override as well to get the similar indicators.

```css
.carousel-indicators {
  /* required to override bootstrap */
  right: unset !important;
  left: unset !important;
  padding-left: 18px !important;
  margin-right: unset !important;
  margin-left: unset !important;
  /* your css styles */
  width: auto;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  background-color: rgba(96, 107, 114, .8);
  border-radius: 18px;
  line-height: 0;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  width: 12px !important;
  height: 12px !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row no-gutters justify-content-center">
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: @ShaswatiBhattacharyya Yes, I've updated my snippet. I've done some changes in html as well to make it center. If you don't want to insert new node, you can do similar styling using the parent classes.